# C# DLL interfacing with MATLAB

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, matlab, dll

I have created a menu in matlab and onclick of the menu I have m script that will call c# DLL. This I have done using add assembly.
And am passing few values to the c# DLL like guid and name. In c# DLL I am invoking a dialogue box with these MATLAB information. 
From the c# dialogue box everytime based on the user selection (using guid) I have to highlight model in matlab. And when the dialogue box is closed I need to update some values in matlab model.
And also When the dialog box is launched I should also able to scroll and zoom in my MATLAB model. I have tried with delegate and event but I can't able to zoom/scroll my MATLAB model. I can't make my dialog box modeless because after invoking I can't able to access my event listener in MATLAB. And also connection between MATLAB and c# is cut and I don't want that to happen.

Comment: My code looks like this and am having a form show dialog apart from the code provided, https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/placeofmemory.wordpress.com/2015/06/11/interfacing-c-and-matlab-using-events/amp/

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code inline rather than linking to it in a comment.